# How to concatenate multiple rows from an other table in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and I need to concatenate in a new column `Suppliers_List` all the suppliers for a given item.

I have a table **Orders** where I need to create the column :

```
Order_Number Customer_ID Item_Number
0001         1           1
0002         2           1
0003         1           3
0004         1           4
0005         3           2
0006         3           2
0007         4           2
```

A table **Items** where a same product can have multiple supplier:

```
Unique_ID Item_Number Supplier_ID Item_Name
1         1           1           "wheel"
2         1           2           "wheel"
3         2           1           "door"
4         2           2           "door"
5         3           1           "motor"
6         3           3           "motor"
7         4           4           "dashboard"
```

And a table **Suppliers** :

```
Supplier_ID Supplier_Name
1           "Metal&co"
2           "SmithSE"
3           "BetterMotors"
4           "TinyCircuits"
```

I'm trying to get the following result in the table **Orders** where I store the suppliers name, separated by a comma :

```
Order_Number Customer_ID Item_Number Suppliers_List
0001         1           1           "Metal&co, SmithSE"
0002         2           1           "Metal&co, SmithSE"
0003         1           3           "Metal&co, BetterMotors"
0004         1           4           "TinyCircuits"
0005         3           2           "Metal&co, SmithSE"
0006         3           2           "Metal&co, SmithSE"
0007         4           2           "Metal&co, SmithSE"
```

I know that the dax expression for my column `Suppliers_List` probably deals with [Concatenate](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dax/concatenate-function-dax) and [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dax/groupby-function-dax) functions but I don't have the knowledge to get it.

The solution I'm thinking of is to group the field `Item_Number` from the table **Items** and concatenate the field `Supplier_Name` from table **Suppliers**.

my not working try :

```
Suppliers_list = CONCATENATE(GROUPBY('Items';Suppliers[Supplier_Name]) ; ", ")
```

Can someone help ?

## UPDATE

I finaly found something way far from my first guess.

See my anwser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found something way far from my first guess.

First, you need to create a new column `Supplier_Name` in the table **Items** where you will store value in the field `Supplier_Name` from **Suppliers**. I've achieve it like so :

```
Supplier_Name = CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER ( Suppliers; Items[Supplier_ID] = Suppliers[Supplier_ID] );
    Suppliers[Supplier_Name];
    ""
)
```

Now that we have our `Supplier_Name` in our table **Items**, we can compute the suppliers list by grouping every product and concatenate the supplier name in a new column `Suppliers_List`.

```
Suppliers_List = CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER ( Items; Items[Item_Number] = EARLIER ( Items[Item_Number] ) );
    Items[Supplier_Name];
    ", "
)
```

You can now import it in a visualization element such as a table.

Hopping that will help the community